# Can't bind the array of objects from .ts to the template (.html) in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

this .ts file where i fill "mesMenus" array i want to print in .html file:

```
export class MenusComponent{
  mesMenus= new Array<Menu>();

  constructor(private gMenuService:GestionMenuService){
    
    this.gMenuService.onAddMenu().subscribe(m =>  {      
      this.mesMenus.push(m);
      console.log(this.mesMenus); // here the array contains elements
                       
    },
  );
  console.log(this.mesMenus); // here becomes empty
  
}
```

here my onAddMenu() method:

```
onAddMenu(): Observable<Menu> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
```

and here the the template (.html):

```
<div class="container">
    <h3 class="text-center mt-3">List des menus</h3>
  <div class="row mt-2" *ngIf="mesMenus.length > 0">
    <div *ngFor="let m of mesMenus" [ngStyle]="{'display': m.display ? 'block' : 'none' }" class="col-md-3">
      <div *ngIf="m.display === true" class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top p-2" src="{{ m.image }}" alt="" />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h3>{{ m.nom }}</h3>
          <p>{{ m.description }}</p>
          <p>{{ m.prix }}</p>
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="onCommander(m)">
            Commander
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

when i print the array in the console, it contains elements but can't get them in the template (.html)

Comment: Can you post what the objects in the array look like, from the console log

Comment: [
    {
        "display": true,
        "nom": "c",
        "description": "",
        "prix": 0,
        "image": "data:image/webp;base64,HHGSBBBBI...",
        "quantityOrdered": 0
    }
] , when i add one element, it is added only when i call subscribe() but outside of it the array is empty

Comment: maybe remove some of the other logic... especially *ngIf="m.display === true"... (response might be inferred type or something...)  I don't think it's unusual that the 2nd console.log doesn't show anything since you've subscribed to an observable to populate the array in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an issue with `push`, even though you are pushing new elements to an array, the array is not been reassigned to a new value, is the same object, so `Angular` doesn't detect any changes for it.

The solution would be to create a new copy based on the original array, work with it, and then assign back the copy to the original array as if it were a different object. Remember that in Javascript, arrays are objects.

```js
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  mesMenus: Menu[] = [];

  constructor(...) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.gMenuService.onAddMenu().subscribe((menuItem) => {
        const copy = [...this.mesMenus]; // a new array based on the original
        copy.push(menuItem);
        this.mesMenus = [...copy]; // reassign a NEW object to the array so changes can be detected
    });
  }
}
```

Additionally, based on your code posted, you are trying to `console.log` the array value **outside** from the `subscribe`, which is always going to be different than `console.log`ging from inside the `subscribe`, why? because of asynchronous code.

When you `subscribe` to an `observable`, that code becomes async, so by the time you are assigning a value to your array, the console log from outside is already executed.

```js
someFunction(): void {
  console.log('1');
  this.myService.getSomething().subscribe(() => console.log('2'));
  console.log('3');
}

//Output would be:
// 1
// 3
// 2
```